# Don't Dismiss Popup On Outside Click

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I have a popup window that I would like to inflate and dismiss programatically, I do not want any user input to dismiss it. However when the screen is touched outside of the pop up the pop up is dismissed, I know this question has been asked before but I've tried every variation I found and I can't seem to make this work... Here is my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_loading, null);
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = false;
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
        popupWindow.setElevation(20);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.transparent_back));
        popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor((View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {return false;});
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);// v is a view passed as a parameter to the function
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The new code:

```
 boolean focusable = false;
 popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

The following was deleted:

```
popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor((View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {return false;});
```